# Data Model Tables visible in Pivot Table Field List but not Data Model itself - Excel 2016

Tags: excel-2016

I've transformed and loaded two tables to Excel's data model from Power Query.

When I create a Pivot Table from the data model, the tables are visible. I can see them and their columns in the field list.

When I open the data model (Data > Manage Data Model or Power Pivot > Manage), there are no tables. How do I get them to appear here so I can create relationships / measures / etc.

My organization has me on Excel 2016 (16.0.5161.10000) MSO (16.0.5161.1002) 32-bit on Windows 10, in case that has something to do with it and it's not just simple user error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a glitch. I closed and reopened the workbook and the tables were in the data model.

I'm not marking this as the accepted answer in case I observe anything else or somebody knows a specific trigger for the issue.